# How can I set data from controller to .phtml file in magento

Tags: magento-2.1, module, custom

I have created a custom module and there are some drop downs in it. I have done all the things in .phtml file as pure php.

How can I change that to correct way code in my .phtml file:

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();

$tableColor = $resource->getTableName('color_price');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $tableColor;
$color = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
?>
```

drop down like below its in .phtml file too:

```
<p><br>Frame Color</p>
<select id="color">
<?php
foreach($color as $c){ ?>
    <option value="<?php print_r($c['price_component']);?>"><?php print_r($c['color']);?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>

<b><p id="framecolor"></p></b>
```

below code is my layout.xml file

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" 
layout="1column">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Test2\Helloworld\Block\Helloworld" 
            name="helloworld" template="helloworld.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> what is the correct way of doing this. now all the things in .phtml file

Comment: Could you please share your layout xml ?

Comment: @Pankaj Pareek Can u look the edited question

Answer (score 1):

In controller file,

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$persistor = $om->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface');
$data = array('test1','test2');
<!-- set data in persistor object -->
$persistor->set('coloroption', $data);
```

In template file,

```
<!-- get data in persistor object -->  

  $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $persistor = $om->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface');
  $colorOption =     $persistor->get('coloroption');
  print_r($colorOption);
```

Comment: Please let me know if you have issue

Comment: if u can please tell me how ur code working i dont understand how it works. how can i connect ur code with mine im new to magento if u can please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be it help you :

```
<?php
$this->_layout
    ->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')
    ->setData($data)
    ->setTemplate('Namespace_Module::templatepath.phtml')
    ->toHtml();
?>
```

Comment: wher shoud i put those things

Comment: In your controller  , Also you can manipulate syntax as per your need .

Answer (score 0):

In your module block class `Test2\Helloworld\Block\Helloworld` add the code as below:

```
namespace Test2\Helloworld\Block;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;

class Helloworld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {
    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    private $objectManager;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    array $data = []
) {

    $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

    public function getFrameColorOption() {
        $resource = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $tableColor = $resource->getTableName('color_price');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $tableColor;
        $color = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
        return $color;
    }
}
```

In your template file, You can call the function as below:

```
$color = $block->getFrameColorOption();
```

PS: We should not use `ObjectManager` directly. If you have created Model for `color_price` table then you should use Model instead of `ObjectManager`

Comment: I try that thing now but it will give a Fatal error. can u tell me how to solve that,

Comment: I have updated my code.

Comment: so is that ok if i write query in block, dont i need to write those things in controller

Comment: Yes template must take data from block instead of controller